# Is the extension of a continuous function on a subspace to the closure of its domain unique?

Tags: general-topology

The following problem is from Munkres's Topology (exercise 13 in section 18 "Continuous Functions"; page 112, 2nd edition).

> Let $A \subset X$; let $f:A \to Y$ be continuous; let $Y$ be a Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ may be extended to a continuous function $g:cl(A)\to  Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

Comment: This is a beautiful result! Please, show us where is your problem.

Comment: And the title is about as useless as it could possibly be.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen at least it isn't "Help me" :).

Comment: To answer your questions, think of the following: (a) what is an extension, i.e. which points of $cl(A)$ do we want to check $g$'s uniqueness on? (b) what else do we know about $g$, and how does that help us?

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Suppose that $g_0:\operatorname{cl}A\to Y$ and $g_1:\operatorname{cl}A\to Y$ both extend $f$. We know that $g_0(x)=g_1(x)$ for each $x\in A$, so suppose that $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$. For convenience let $y_0=g_0(x)$ and $y_1=g_1(x)$. Suppose that $y_0\ne y_1$; $Y$ is Hausdorff, so there are open sets $U_0$ and $U_1$ in $Y$ such that $y_0\in U_0$, $y_1\in U_1$, and $U_0\cap U_1=\varnothing$.

> **Note:** Everything that I’ve done up to here is just ‘following my nose’, i.e., doing the most natural, straightforward thing that *might* work; it’s the sort of preliminary reasoning that should quickly become nearly automatic. For instance, if you want to prove that something is unique, one obvious approach is to assume that it **isn’t** unique and try to get a contradiction; that’s what I’m doing here. That gives me the distinct points $y_0$ and $y_1$; now what is there in the statement of the problem that naturally goes with having a pair of distinct points in $Y$? Here that’s easy. The hypothesis that $Y$ is Hausdorff immediately tells me something about those two points: they can be separated by disjoint open nbhds, and I might as well do it and see whether it’s useful.

And here’s the rest of the hint: let $V_0=g_0^{-1}[U_0]$ and $V_1=g_1^{-1}[U_1]$, and consider the sets $V_0\cap A$ and $V_1\cap A$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Thx. However, that is exactly where I failed to continue. What is the contradiction then? I would expect to show that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$ (thus, contrary to $x \in \bar{A} \setminus A$), but I failed to get that. Could you offer me some more hints?

Comment: I think I have found the solution. Following your arguments, we can consider the set $V_0 \cap V_1$. First, $V_0 \cap V_1$ is an open set of $X$. Second, $x \in V_0 \cap V_1$. Third, $V_0 \cap V_1 \subset \bar{A} \setminus A$. In all, we obtain a neighbor (i.e., $V_0 \cap V_1$) of $x$ does not intersect $A$. Therefore, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: @hengxin How did you conclude that $V_0 \cap V_1 \subset \bar{A} \setminus A$.

Comment: @Muno Sorry, I have forgotten it. I taught myself a little bit about topology about 4 years ago. I find it not easy for me to pick them up. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Muno I think we can't conclude $V_0 \cap V_1 \subset \bar{A} \setminus A$. It might be better to consider $x \in V_0 \cap V_1$ where $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$. Then by definition of limit point, any neighborhood of $x$ ...

Comment: I see that $V_0$ and $V_1$ are disjoint sets that both include x. Is that correct?

Comment: @DannyuNDos: Almost: $V_0\cap A=f^{-1}[U_0]$ and $V_1\cap A=f^{-1}[U_1]$ are disjoint sets that both contain $x$. $V_0\cap V_1$ can be non-empty, but it must be contained in $(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$.